# Joomla 3 transfer parent title variable of active menu item

Tags: php, variables, menu, joomla3.0

Thanks to all of you I have been able to create a variable: $mytitle from the active parent menu item in Joomla 3.

This is my code:

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$parent = $menu->getItem( $menu->getActive()->parent_id );
$parentname = $parent->title;
$parentlink = JRoute::_( $parent->link . '&Itemid=' . $parent->id );
$menulevel = $menu->getActive()->level; $activename= $menu->getActive()->title;  
$mytitle = ($menulevel == 1)?$activename:$parentname;
echo $mytitle;
```

This works great but now I need to use it on my submenu item (VMenuBlock). The code is as follows and I cannot seem to figure out how to place the variable so that it works?

```
function modChrome_vmenu($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
  if (!empty ($module->content)) {
    if (function_exists('VMenuBlock'))
      echo VMenuBlock(($module->showtitle != 0) ? $module->title : '', $module->content,
        $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));
    else
      echo Block(($module->showtitle != 0) ? $module->title : '', $module->content,
        $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!,
Thanks!
Doug